# How to detect GPS being enabled

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm making an app which uses GPS. The problem comes when you open the app without having GPS enabled, it does nothing (obviously) but if you enable GPS without exiting the app then the app still doing nothing. As I need to disable and enable GPS in my app I would need to know where the problem comes from, I'll leave you here some code:

```
public class EscuchaLocalizacion implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager gestor;
    private TextView view1;
    private TextView view2;

    private boolean registrado;
    private static final float minDistance = 10.0f;
    private static final long minTime = 300;

    public double _LONG;
    public double _LAT;

    EscuchaLocalizacion (Context c, TextView t1, TextView t2) {

        Log.v("EscuchaLocalizacion", "Construyendo el objeto");

        gestor = (LocationManager) c.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        registrado = false;

        view1 = t1;
        view2 = t2;

        Log.v("EscuchaLocalizacion", "He terminado de construir el objeto");

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        _LONG = arg0.getLongitude();
        _LAT = arg0.getLatitude();
        view1.setText(Double.toString(_LONG));
        view2.setText(Double.toString(_LAT));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg0.contentEquals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Log.w("EscucharLocalizacion","Provider: " 
                    + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER + " was disabled");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!registrado && arg0.contentEquals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            registrar();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void registrar() {

        if (gestor.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){

            Log.i("EscucharLocalizacion", "Registrado a " + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            gestor.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, 
                                        minDistance, this);
            registrado = true;

        }else {

            Log.w("EscucharLocalizacion", "No se pudo registrar a " + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            registrado = false;
        }
    }

    public void anularRegistro(){

        gestor.removeUpdates(EscuchaLocalizacion.this);
        registrado = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you initialize EscuchaLocalizacion?

You need to search location in onResume () and stop searching onPause location in your activity.

**start locating:**
escuchaLocalizacion.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 00, 0, gpsLocationListener);

**stop locating:**
escuchaLocalizacion.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);

If you have a checkbox to enable/disable GPS localisation, you can add a listener on the checkbox then put this functions there if you want to use GPS or not.

Also don't forget to add this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```